# Creating clickstream sequence from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, path, journey, clickstream

I have the following table:

| User ID | Session ID | Time Stamp | Page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:01 | 1 |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:02 | 2 |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:05 | 3 |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:10 | 4 |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:11 | 5 |
| 122 | 1299.1 | HH:MM:01 | 2 |
| 122 | 1299.1 | HH:MM:02 | 3 |
| 128 | 124.4 | HH:MM:01 | 1 |
| 128 | 124.4 | HH:MM:02 | 2 |

And, I am trying to get a table like this:

| User ID | Session ID | Time Stamp | Page | Next Page | Duration (secs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:01 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:02 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:05 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 123 | 123.4 | HH:MM:10 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| 122 | 1299.1 | HH:MM:01 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 128 | 124.4 | HH:MM:01 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

I know I have to use lead(), but I cannot figure out how to use the mutate and lead function together.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the `Duration (sec)` variable calculating?

Comment: @guasi, It is duration in seconds. So, I am calculating the difference between the below and above timestamps.

Comment: Your numbers on `Duration (sec)` are not the result of the difference between **below** and **above** timestamps. In row 3, that calculation would be 10 (below) - 2 (above) = 8. It seems you want self and below, which would give you 2-1 = 1, 5-3 = 3, 10-5 = 5, 10 - nothing = 10. In this scenario, `Duration` for row 4 should be 10, not 1. Or how are you calculating the result of row 4?

Comment: I assumed in my previous question you are calculating duration between timestamps in a **single session**. Is that the case?

Comment: @guasi, it is by user id and session id too.

Comment: So how are you calculating Duration for row 4? see my question above?

Comment: @guasi, for user 123 and session id 123.4, the duration is 2-1 = 1, 5-2 = 3, 10-5 = 5, and 11-10 = 1.

Comment: I tried using this:
df <- df %>% select (timestamp, sessionid, userid, page) %>%
arrange(timestamp, sessionid) %>%
mutate (nextpage = lead (page))

But, I know this is incomplete. I need help figuring the rest out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility using `dplyr`. It's not very elegant, perhaps someone else can come up with something more succinct.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
~ ID, ~ Session, ~ Timestamp, ~ Pages,
123, 123.4,  01, 1,
123, 123.4,  02, 2,
123, 123.4,  05, 3,
123, 123.4,  10, 4,
123, 123.4,  11, 5,
122, 1299.1, 01, 2,
122, 1299.1, 02, 3,
128, 124.4,  01, 1,
128, 124.4,  02, 2)


df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Session) %>% 
  mutate(Duration = lead(Timestamp) - Timestamp) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
     ID Session Timestamp Pages Duration
  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1   123    123.         1     1        1
2   123    123.         2     2        3
3   123    123.         5     3        5
4   123    123.        10     4        1
5   122   1299.         1     2        1
6   128    124.         1     1        1
```